# Firefox : execute javascript in xslt

Tags: javascript, firefox, xslt

I have written an xslt document to transform an xml file in html. Now I would like to pass a parameter from the url to a xslt variable, so that I can display a specific xml entry from the xml document in Firefox 9.0.1. To do so, I use a javascript function that returns me the value of the url parameter. Now my question : Is it possible in Firefox to pass the return value of the javascript function to a xslt variable?

Thanks a lot for an answer!

Comment: The xslt runs before JavaScript does. Not going to happen that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [querystring using xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811006/querystring-using-xslt)

Comment: How are you executing the transform?  Are you loading an XML file with a processing instruction for the XSLT, or are you loading an HTML file with JavaScript to transform an XML file?

Comment: I'm using an xml file with <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./test.xsl"?>

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might work.

XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select='*[name()="__TAG_NAME__"]' />
```

JS (jQuery assumed; also, W3C-code only, not IE)

```
var tagName = location.href.match(/tagName=([^&]+)/),
    output;
if (tagName) {
    $.ajax({url: 'path/to/xsl.xsl', dataType: 'text'}).done(function(xsl) {
        var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl.replace('__TAG_NAME__', tagName[1]);
        var doc = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
        output = doc.innerHTML;
    });
}
```