# XSL: Using a dynamic select list to generate a filtered list

Tags: xslt, recursion, drop-down-menu

I have a XML file of names and phone numbers and the cities associated with them (could be multiple cities). What I want to do is generate a unique list of cities and then let the user select one of the cities. When they do a list of all the names that are associated with that city is displayed.

I can generate the unique list of cities. I can generate the names associated with a hardcoded city. I can make the name/phone list visible or invisible when the city is selected. What I can't do is figure out how to use the select list "selected" value to filter the names. I realize this is probably trivial, but be kind to a newb and tell me how it's done!

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var showList = function() {
    document.getElementById("swarms").style.visibility = "visible";
    <xsl:variable name="thisOne" select="'document.allCities.select.options[document.allCities.select.selectedIndex].value'" />
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Display list of cities -->
    <div id="city_list">
    <xsl:variable name="unique-list" select="swarmlist/member/cities/city[not(.=following::city)]" />

        <form name="allCities">
        <strong>Select A City and Click the Button to Display the List: </strong> 
        <select name="select">              
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <xsl:for-each select="$unique-list">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
            <option>
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </option>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </select>
      <input name="submit" type="button" value="Display" onclick="showList();" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <!-- End of City list -->

    <!-- Display list of volunteers -->
   <table border="1" id="swarms" style="visibility:hidden">
     <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="swarmlist/member">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="cities/city = $thisOne">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  <!-- End of volunteer list -->

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to define a XSLT variable based on a Javascript expression. As far as I know, that will not work because XSLT is processed *before* the page is rendered, and before any Javascript is executed. In other words, you can't use XSLT to dynamically change the content of a page based on user actions.

You could try to change your button to a real `<input type="submit">` and let the page to reload when the user clics on it. This way, you would have the selected city as a request parameter, and you could read it into your `$thisOne` variable.

I've never captured request parameters in XSLT myself, but hopefully, this may help you:
[querystring using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811006/querystring-using-xslt)

Another approach, much easier (and extremely inefficient) would be to parse the whole list into different `<div>` blocks, and then use Javascript to hide them and show the correct one.